# 64-bit integer declaration in C

Tags: c, types

I was trying to declare 64bit variable in C with unsigned long long datatype but it not working and behaving similar to uint32 bit variable. What is the solution to access / check the bit above 32 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    printf("Hello world");
    unsigned long long temp = 0x1234567890123456ULL;
    unsigned long long temp2 = temp >> 1;
    
    uint64_t var = 0x1234567890123456; 
    
    printf("\n%x", (long long) temp); 
    printf("\n%x", (long long) temp2); 
    printf("\n%x", 1ULL << 31ULL);
    printf("\n%x", 1ULL << 32ULL);
    
    printf("\n%x", var); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Hello world
>
> 90123456
>
> 48091a2b
>
> 80000000
>
> 0
>
> 90123456

Comment: You are telling `printf()` to print `unsigned int` and not `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: Did the compiler not give you warnings when you compiled the code? Both clang and gcc warn about this by default and tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

You used wrong format specifier for `printf()`. `%x` is for printing `unsigned int`. Mismatch in format specifier and actual data in `printf()` invokes *undefined behavior*.

To print integers in hexadecimal, you should use `%llx` for `unsigned long long` and `PRIx64` (from `inttypes.h`) for `uint64_t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    printf("Hello world");
    unsigned long long temp = 0x1234567890123456ULL;
    unsigned long long temp2 = temp >> 1;
    
    uint64_t var = 0x1234567890123456; 
    
    printf("\n%llx", (long long) temp); 
    printf("\n%llx", (long long) temp2); 
    printf("\n%llx", 1ULL << 31ULL);
    printf("\n%llx", 1ULL << 32ULL);
    
    printf("\n%" PRIx64, var); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "To print integers in hexadecimal..." hmm... to me that's not clear/correct. Should it be "To print 64 bit integers...."

Comment: The casts to `long long` should also be removed.  The specifier expects `unsigned long long` so we shouldn't pass a `signed long long`.